# Find a cell in a 2D extensor table based on colum values

Tags: visual-c++, xtensor

I want to read one cell of a 2D xtensor table based on a matching cell in a column in the table.

Conside a 2D table of elements of type std::string:

```
+-----+---+---+---+
| fee | I | J | K |
+-----+---+---+---+
| fie | L | M | N |
+-----+---+---+---+
| fo  | O | P | Q |
+-----+---+---+---+
| fum | R | S | T |
+-----+---+---+---+
```

I want to read the value of the 3rd cell in the row where the first column == 'fo', ie 'P'

Searches on the internet suggest code that uses the function xt::keep() which seems not to be implemented. How do I carry this out using xt functions that *are* actually implemented?

Comment: `xt::keep()` is implemented. Which version of xtensor are you using?
P.S.: you should use `xt::keep()` together with a view method https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/view.html

Answer (score 1):

You can check where in your array is there an element equal to "fo". The result, in this case would be the index {2, 0}. Than you can use the first element of that index (2) and the desired column index (2) and get a view of the array in the desired position.

Like this:

```cpp
#include <xtensor/xtensor.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>
#include "xtensor/xview.hpp"

int main()
{
    xt::xarray<std::string> arr{{"fee", "i", "j", "k"},
                                {"fie", "l", "m", "n"},
                                {"fo", "o", "p", "q"},
                                {"fum", "r", "s", "t"}};

    auto indices = xt::where(xt::equal(arr, std::string("fo"))) // indices = {{2}, {0}}
    auto result = xt::view(arr, xt::keep(indices[0]), xt::keep(2)) // result = {"p"}
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it makes sense. I'm using MS Visual Studio 2017 and have installed xtensor 0.15.10 via cmake in its NuGet Package Manager. This is the latest xtensor version available to it. I think this version does not contain xt::keep which is why it won't compile with ::keep because it's not an xt member. Do you have any suggestions on how to update xtensor in Visual Studio 2017 to 0.23?

Comment: You can use vcpkg (https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg) to install it. It will be 0.21.9, at least.

Comment: Follow the installation instructions and then run: `vcpkg install xtensor:x64-windows`, `vcpkg install xtensor-io:x64-windows`; and `vcpkg install xtensor-blas:x64-windows` (if you need blas methods)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I used vcpkg and it installed smoothly and works fine. FYI I had to uninsall the xtensor that I installed with CMake/NuGet in Visual Studio: Visual Studio seemed to use that version and ignore the vcpkg version.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of @TaiguaraTupinambás I would like to suggest you not to use `xt::view` at all when you want to get a specific element from an array (or "matrix" or "table" in your 2d case). For your example I would do:

```cpp
#include <xtensor/xtensor.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>

int main()
{
    xt::xtensor<std::string, 2> arr =
        {{"fee", "I", "J", "K"},
         {"fie", "L", "M", "N"},
         {"fo" , "O", "P", "Q"},
         {"fum", "R", "S", "T"}};

    auto indices = xt::from_indices(xt::argwhere(xt::equal(arr, std::string("fo"))));
    auto row = indices(0, 0);
    std::cout << arr(row, 2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that `row` is simply an index (of type `size_t`). Now `arr(row, 2)` is a reference (of type `std::string&`) to the element you were looking for. This is I think cleaner than using `xt::view` in this case, and it will turn out to be much faster too.

Comment: Thanks - I see how that's more efficient.

Comment: `xt::view` would useful when indices return multiple values, maybe? If there were multiple lines where the first column is equal to "fo".

Comment: @TaiguaraTupinambás Yeah sure, if you want take a slice of size > 0 `xt::view` is the way to go. Not entirely sure if your `indices[0]` syntax work then? It could be good to check.

Comment: How do I find the column heading that matches a particular value? To find the index of the cell In the table header that contains "fee" I tried: auto row_header = xt::view(arr, 0, xt::all()); to get the header row, and then auto temp = xt::from_indices(xt::argwhere(xt::equal(row_header, "fee"))); But when I try to get the position of "fee" in the header by temp(0) I get an exception.

Comment: @ChrisS `from_indices` always returns and array of dimension 2. For a list, you can just use `ravel_indices`. See https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/indices.html#from-array-indices-to-flat-indices

Comment: @ChrisS your error might also be because of the expression `xt::argwhere(xt::equal(row_header, "fee"))`. Try replacing `"fee"` by `"std::string("fee")`.

Comment: Thanks: I changed "fo" to std::string("fo") and refered to the index as temp(0,0) and that worked. Tom said the indeces will be 2D hence the treatment of temp. That worked.

Comment: Thanks: I changed "fee" to 
    std::string("fee") 

and refered to the index as temp(0,0) and that worked. Tom said the indeces will be 2D hence the treatment of temp. 

Then I changed the line to try ravel_indices & based on the xtensor docs it needs a second parameter of the object's shape, hence: 
    auto temp = xt::ravel_indices (xt::argwhere(xt::equal(row_header, std::string("fee"))), row_header.shape()); 

This line shows no errors when I enter it into the VS IDE, but it compiles with errors in the xtensor header files of all places, not my code:

Comment: There were 11 errors that refer to xtensor.hpp & xutils.hpp. List of first 5: 
Code Description | File | Line
C2027 use of undefined type 'xt::rebind_container<ptrdiff_t,S>' | utils.hpp | 830 
C2061 syntax error: identifier 'type' | xutils.hpp | 830 
C2794 'type': is not a member of any direct or indirect base class of 'xt::get_strides_type<S>' | xutils.hpp | 843
C2938 'xt::get_strides_t' : Failed to specialize alias template | xtensor.hpp | 893
C2672 'make_sequence': no matching overloaded function found | xtensor.hpp | 894

Comment: Next 3: 
Code Description | File | Line
C2770 invalid explicit template argument(s) for 'S xtl::make_sequence(S::size_type,S::value_type)' | xtensor.hpp | 894
C2780 'S xtl::make_sequence(S::size_type)': expects 1 arguments - 2 provided | xtensor.hpp | 894
C2672 'compute_strides': no matching overloaded function found | xtensor.hpp | 895

Comment: Last 3: 
Code Description | File | Line
C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'size_t xt::compute_strides(const shape_type &,xt::layout_type,strides_type &)' | xtensor.hpp | 895
C2672 'element_offset': no matching overloaded function found | xtensor.hpp | 901
C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'offset_type xt::element_offset(const S &,It,It) noexcept' | xtensor.hpp | 901

Comment: @ChrisS Maybe its best if you ask another question, that will easier to read and to answer